# How to send new build to tester in fabric?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I'm working on fabrics. I add

```
   [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
```

in AppDelegate.

I send build 1.0 to my 3rd party tester now how do i send update to(Build 1.1) to him ?

Answer (score 0):

Just upload the new 1.1 version to Beta and enter all their e-mail address when submitting the app.

The beta test will receive an e-mail that the 1.1 version is available for testing. User still running the test version will also see message in the app that a new test version is available.

Comment: I added the app with Build 1.1 but it still shows Build 1.0 in fabrics.

Comment: Did you use the Fabric tool bar app? You should see a version drop down on fabric.IO where you can select the version of you app.

Comment: Yes I'm using tool bar app.I added new build in bar and visit fabric.IO, but there's only  Build 1.0 but in crash report there is build 1.0 & 1.1.

Comment: organization ? means ?

Comment: You can have multiple organization with your Fabric profile. It is possible to add app with the same bundle ID to different bundle ID's.

Comment: Ok Gotcha... Till now i add a full app code to fabric, but after creating archive it working. Thx

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that my provisioning profile was wrong. I changed it from my development one to AdHoc and it worked.